# How do I enable data.table from SQL

Tags: sql-server, r, data.table

In the "R Interactive" tab, I can access data.table. Installr loaded it in my personal folder.
But when I'm trying to use R from SQL

```sql
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
  @language = N'R'         
, @input_data_1 = N' select top 2 TodayClosed as Closed, Industry from stockquotes SQ
     inner join StockSymbols SS on SS.ID = SQ.StockId where TodayClosed is not null;'    
, @script = N'
     dtf <- data.frame(InputDataSet)
     dt <- data.table(dtf)
     dt[,list(mean=mean(Closed),sd=sd(Closed)),by=Industry]'
WITH RESULT SETS (([mean] float NULL, [sd] float NULL, Industry char(75) NULL));
```

I get this error:

> could not find function "data.table"

From other error messages, I'd say it is looking under 'Program Files'.
I've tried installing it there with no luck.

Comment: The question is missing a **lot** of information. You are talking about SQL Server's *R Services*. This requires SQL Server 2016 and installation of the services in the first place. You mention other error messages but *dont'* post them. I'd bet you just forgot to import the packages you need. Post *all* the error messages and explain explicitly what you installed. Have you added the appropriate packages?

Comment: In any case **DON'T** make random installations and modifications. You'll probably end up wrecking R, SQL Server, your machine or all of them. Neither R or SQL Server are broken. Can you execute any of the samples in the docs?

Comment: First, have you *installed* `data.table` ? That's a *separate* package that has to be loaded as show in [Installing and Managing R packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709429.aspx)

Comment: Second, why `data.table`? It will probably be *slower* than the equivalent SQL statement, because it will have to reload the same data twice and calculate the aggregates *after* loading. If you changed your query to a `SELECT AVG(..),STDEV(..)` you'd get the result in the same time it took the query to execute

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm painfully aware that using straight SQL I could have been done weeks ago.  8: -(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to install the data.table package into a location that R Services can find. When SQL runs an R stored proc, it uses a different user account to your own. Per the [MSDN documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx)

> **Step 3: Enable Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts**
>
> During setup, 20 new Windows user accounts are created for the purpose of running tasks under the security token of the SQL Server Trusted Launchpad service. When a user sends an R script from an external client, SQL Server will activate an available worker account, map it to the identity of the calling user, and run the R script on behalf of the user.

Because of this, any packages installed under your user directory tree won't be found. The default location where R Services looks for packages is something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\library`, but you probably shouldn't install new packages there or you risk breaking things. Instead, choose or create a different, globally accessible directory to install into.

Second, you have to load data.table into your R session. Insert

```
.libPaths("packagedir")
require(data.table)
```

at the top of your R script, where `packagedir` is the directory you chose.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Between comments by PK and Hong Ooi, I was able to get this resolved. I was trying to install the package from RServices but it didn't have permission. Going to the CLI resolved that. Interestingly, it had a dependency on chron that I had to install manually.